# Does my templates directory need a __init__.py file?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I have the following in my project hierarchy ...

```
+ project
    + web
        + views
            tax_calculator.py
        + forms
            __init__.py
            tax_calculator_form.py
        + templates
            tax_calculator.html
```

My view file, "tax_calculator.py" is attempting to render a GET request, using

```
# Basic function that serves the default page
def get(request):
    tax_calculator_form = TaxCalculatorForm()
    return render(request, "web/templates/tax_calculator.html", {'form': tax_calculator_form})
```

but I'm getting the error

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /calculate_taxes
```

when I visit my URL and it's complaining about this line in my view

```
return render(request, "web/templates/tax_calculator.html", {'form': tax_calculator_form})
```

The path looks correct to me.  Why isn't my URL finding my template path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your questions title, No. `__init__.py` is for python modules, not asset directories

Depending on how you've specified your [template settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#templates), you shouldn't need the relative path, `"tax_calculator.html"` should suffice.

Comment: Ah, it was set to just "templates" as opposed to the actual path -- "web/templates".  Thx

Comment: @Dave - No worries, you may like to see the link I've added for the settings, in particular the `APP_DIRS` option